# Getting and presenting a database table on page load

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Booststrap CSS library to display my database in a grid table. I have a php class that handles the connection to a database. I would like an html page to pull the info from the database and put it into a table on two occasions, on page load, and when a user adds a new element to the database (there is a form on the same page that allows someone to add an element). So how can I call a php class method from html to connect to my db and pull data. Also is it better to have a php function that can draw the Bootstrap grid, or should I just pull one element at a time from the table and use javascript to fill out my table right on the html page?

Comment: to call something php from "html", you probably should use ajax (javascript). there are multiple frameworks out there, jquery is very common.

Comment: I would like to keep it as vanilla as possible without having to use jquery or any other framework. Is it doable?

Comment: well a framework just does most of the work for you (especially when it comes to fine differences between browsers). But of course you can do this all without frameworks. You should read up on XMLHttpRequest then.

Comment: So it's not possible to get the whole table from a database without using ajax? I was thinking of something like <html> <run script on page load> --> calls my php class method which draws the table.

Comment: html is not a programming language, it's a markup language. however, php is a programming language. When you say "i would like an html page to pull the info from the database", it's ... confusing. you can generate a html page in php, that contains the data. For that we would need some information about your php class ... (Ajax is for when the page is already displayed in the browser, to load additional stuff, like a table, but it's usually easier to have the content already in place)

Comment: So how would I call a php class method with javascript on page load (just plain javascript not with jquery). edit: sorry I didn't mean to say html would call the script, how can I use javascript to call a php method on page load. Its a basic -> class DBConnect { function connectToDB(); function getTable(); function drawTable(); }

Comment: This site is to solve problems, not to provide *all* the code. As I said, XMLHttpRequest is the thing to go. If you have no idea how to code, you probably shouldn't start this. Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: I don't want all the code, I just need one line of code that would call my script. If you can't help you probably shouldn't answer questions.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I provided a keyword, which would provide you with the opportunity to learn something about a topic, which is very closely related to your question, upon whose understanding you could probably solve at least part of your problem. Since your problem is still very unspecific, and you're apparently unwilling to put in any work, I assumed you just want someone to code for you and not work on the solution yourself.

Comment: Maybe you who misunderstands, I read about xmlhttprequest and it's used to implement ajax, which is not something I want to do if I have any other choice. So I asked if there is any way of doing what I want without ajax. I asked I could use javascript to call the php or something. It's just so far you've been taking me in circles, what else do you need to know about my class other than it got those 3 methods I listed? So with no particular answer, I'd rather wait for someone more knowledge on the subject.